# many2one default value with a one2many relation

Tags: odoo

I have the following code :

```
class table_a(osv.osv):
    _name = "table.a"
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('name', size=64),
        'link_to_b': fields.one2many('table.b', 'link_to_a', 'Link to B'),
        }
table_a()

class table_b(osv.osv):
    _name = "table.b"
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('name', size=64),
        'link_to_a': fields.many2one('table.a', 'link_to_a'),
        }
table_b()
```

(And a simple xml to get form and tree with these columns)

When I create a record in table.b through the list 'Link to B' in a form of table.a, is it possible to have the default value of the link with a in 'link_to_a' ? How ?

Thanks in advance.